# Html file not inserting in Mysql table

Tags: html, mysql, c

I'm trying to insert a local html file 'test.html' into a table in mysql,where I'm working on a mysql server through embedded c code.  however I'm getting an access denied error, when trying to insert that html file.

```
void clrstr(char *buf){
    buf[0] = '\0';
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    MYSQL mysql;
    MYSQL_RES *res;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    MYSQL_FIELD *field;
    char query[MAX_QUERY];
    int x;
    int i = 0;

    char *records[] = {
        "LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.html' INTO TABLE students"};

    mysql_init(&mysql);
    mysql_options(&mysql, MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP, "mydb");
    if (!mysql_real_connect(&mysql, HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD,
        DATABASE, 0, NULL, 0)) {
       error("Could not connect to host.",&mysql);
    }

    clrstr(query);
    /* varchar max*/
    strcat(query, "create table students (id int not null auto_increment, fileaa text(65535),primary key(id))");

    printf("Creating students table.\n");

    /*
        Create students table
    */
    if(mysql_query(&mysql, query)){
      error("Could not create table!",&mysql);
    }

    clrstr(query);

    /*
        Insert a records into the students table
    */

    printf("Inserting students.\n");

    for(x = 0; x < 1; x++){
        if(mysql_query(&mysql, records[x])){
            printf("Failure to insert: %s\n",records[x]);
            error("Could not insert record",&mysql);
        }
    }

    clrstr(query);

    /*
        Let us look at what we inserted
    */
    strcpy(query, "select * from students order by last_name");

    if(mysql_query(&mysql, query))
      error("failed select 1",&mysql);

    /*
        Store results from query into res structure.
    */
    if (!(res = mysql_store_result(&mysql))){
        error("failed store 1",&mysql);
    }

    /*
        print all results
    */
    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res))) {
        for (i=0; i < mysql_num_fields(res); i++){
            printf("%s ", row[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    /*
        Drop the students table
    */

    strcpy(query, "drop table students");

    if(mysql_query(&mysql,query))
      error("fail drop 1",&mysql);

    /*
        Finally close connection to server
    */
    mysql_close(&mysql);

    printf("All done\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I tried adding this line :`GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'james'@'localhost'` on this line:

```
 strcat(query, "GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'james'@'localhost',create table students (id int not null auto_increment, fileaa text(65535),primary key(id))");
```

But then I end up getting a syntax error on that line instead. I'm not sure how to go about inserting this file into my database when I keep getting permission errors.

Comment: What do `php` has something to do with this?

Comment: Why are you reading from an HTML file? Shouldn't it be a text file of data?

Comment: I believe your not using blob here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into mysqladmin and run

```
mysql> use mysql;
mysql> GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON yourdb.* TO james@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> \q
```

You should have permissions to all the tables in your db as long as you are connecting as james from localhost.